# processingjs reaching sketch value without function

Tags: javascript, processing

Good afternoon everyone;

I am working with processingjs and I realize one characteristic feature of processingjs;

I have a sketch file called mysketch1.pde and inside of my sketch I just declared int x=5; for test purposes. Thus, mysketch1.pde includes a method called getX() which is a getter for x value.

Lets say, I want to reach this value and print it on my web page. If I write my java script like that I have a problem;

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var mysketch  = Processing.getInstanceById("mysketch1");    


        if(mysketch==null){
            window.alert("it is null");     
        }

        else 
            window.alert(mysketch.getX());
    </script>
```

In this code mysketch variable returns null all the time. (I am including my sketch before javascript on the head section)

However, If I put a button to my web page and call the same code as function it works perfectly;

```
<script type="text/javascript">

     function click(){

        var mysketch  = Processing.getInstanceById("mysketch1");        
        if(mysketch==null){
            window.alert("it is null");     
        }
        else 
            window.alert(mysketch.getX());
            }
    </script>
 <button type="button" onclick="click()">place</button>
```

I assume this stuation happends because somehow javascript works before my .pde file is loaded.I would like to display value of X after .pde is loaded automatically. Do you know how can I cope with this problem?

Regards,

Comment: A bit of a hack, but could you poll `getX()` until it becomes not `null`? I don't know JS, but something like `var x = getX(); while(x != null){ sleep(1); x = getX();}`?

Comment: Dear Kevin;
Thanks for your answer. I used setTimeout() function to cope with this issue. So I let my getX() method wait until. Sketch is ready.

Comment: I just realized I had a typo in my comment, I meant `while(x == null)`... oh well. Glad you got it working. I'll post it as an answer for future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

You should put your code on the `window.onload` event:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var mysketch = Processing.getInstanceById("mysketch1");    
    if (mysketch === null) {
        window.alert("it is null");     
    } else { 
        window.alert(mysketch.getX());
    }
}
```

Comment: Dear Zord;
Unfortunately, it does same thing. I also tried onLoad event for body tag.

Answer (score 0):

One way to get around this would be to poll the `getX()` function until the sketch becomes ready, like setting a timeout to wait until the variable is not null. This approach could also be used to check when the sketch in general is ready, like having a function `isReady(){ return true;}` and waiting until it is not null to run the rest of your script.